# ASP NET MVC Core 2 Roles without database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using Active Directory to manage my users and their respective roles, both of these are correctly brought back.

I am then trying to assign the roles through `ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsType.Role, user.Role));` when debugging I can see that the role is assigned and I don't get any errors.

In my home controller I've added `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on the IActionResult of About, but when I navigate to the About page I'm thrown back to the login.

The user is authorized, as I put `[Authorize]` on Contact and can access this page after login.

What have I missed that's stopping the roles data attribute being used?

**Account Controller login code:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var usr = await AuthorisationCore.AuthenticateUser(model.Username, model.Password);

            if(usr.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // setting up claims identity
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usr.Username),
                };
                // adding role to the claim
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookie");
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usr.Role));
                // new claim principal with the identity of the user input
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("SecurityCookie", principal, new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            });

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Startup code:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // data attributes like [AllowAnonymous]
    services.AddAuthorization();
    // allows for use of cookies and to add options to them
    services
        .AddAuthentication("SecurityCookie")
        .AddCookie("SecurityCookie", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.SlidingExpiration = true;
            cfg.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            cfg.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` from your controller and inspecting the actual claims on the `ClaimsPrincipal` inside the code to see if there's a notable difference.

Comment: @serpent5 okay, thanks for the suggestion, is there anything particularly I should be keeping my eye out for?

Comment: I'd be looking for the name of the claim itself - You might be having an issue with claims transformation and so the `Authorize` attribute-triggered processing may be comparing two different claim types, for example.

Comment: @serpent5 thanks, had a look and it was showing the correct information in the ClaimsPrincipal I just closed the browser, cleared cache and logged in. It worked, so perhaps I'm not disposing of the cookie properly. Using FireFox

Comment: in your contact action, try adding `User.Identity` and check the claims and roles in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

You must use both `app.UseAuthorization();` and `app.UseAuthentication();` in the startup `Configure` function