# Issue: The URL (https://localhost:****/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fIndex) showsup after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
     [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(UsersViewModel users)
        {          
            UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
            var roleUser = login.UserAuthentication(users);
            string message = "";
            switch(roleUser.UserId)
            {
                case -1:
                    message = "Username or Password is incorrect";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    message = "Account has not been activated";
                    break;
                default:
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, users.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), false, roleUser.Roletype, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                    string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                    {
                        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                    }
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ReturnUrl"]))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(Request.Form["ReturnUrl"].Split('/')[2]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View(users);
        }
```

RouteConfig

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Web.config

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">      
      <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

login.chtml

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Home.chtml

```
 [Authorize(Roles ="Admin,Client,Staff")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

UserLogin.cs

```
 public class UserLogin
    {
        public SqlConnection sqlConn;
        private void connection()
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Utils.GetConnection());
        }

        public (int UserId,string Roletype) UserAuthentication(UsersViewModel users)
        { 
            connection();
            sqlConn.Open();            
            (var userid, var roletype) = sqlConn.QuerySingle<(int, string)>("usp_UserValidation", new { users.UserName, users.Password }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);           
            sqlConn.Close();            
            return (userid, roletype);
        }
    }
```

UserViewModel

```
[Display(Name ="User Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Username field is mandatory")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password field is mandatory")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
```

The above action method to validate user given data. The first 2 case works fine. When the correct credentials given like (admin,admin), it fail to redirect. It comes to the **RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")** line of code and then it goes to end of the method. Don't get much understanding what mistake I've made.

FYR: https://ibb.co/hFGJxsW

Comment: @Phong Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

What is UsersViewModel?  What is UserLogin?  Just do it this way:

[Implement and completely understand this link with a brand new project](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17736/How-to-create-and-assign-roles-in-aspnet-mvc-5/32014#.XmZ7v6hKiUk)

Add Authorize attribute to Home or the controller you want to require Authorization

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Client,Staff")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Comment: UserViewModel contains represents **Users** data  to display on the view. UserLogin its a class file which handles the business logic. I will update the both in my questionnaire.

Comment: UserLogin should be a class, but you only have the same named as a method.  Can you please show the UserLogin class?

Comment: Updated the UserLogin class

Answer (score 0):

First of all credit goes to https://github.com/leeenglestone/ASP.NET-Identity-Without-a-Database  and  [ASP NET MVC Core 2 Roles without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396023/asp-net-mvc-core-2-roles-without-database)

This will work for you, by creating a model project that you can then get working for you, in your target application.

Download and fire up https://github.com/leeenglestone/ASP.NET-Identity-Without-a-Database

2)  In AccountController.cs add the identity.AddClaim so the method will look like this

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var identity = await CustomUserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Add this attribute to the HomeController

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Client,Staff")]
```

You should be good to go.